# Dynamic subject with ampscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I solicit you for the creation of an ampscript code to dynamically change the subject of an email in an automation.

I explain I have an email that sent every day but the object is back and hard blow is quite repetitive.

I would like to start with a different object by day of the week.

I think we have to adapt this function

```
%%[

VAR @Date, @Subject
SET @Date = FORMAT(DateAdd(Now(), "X","D"), "ddddd")

SET @Subject = ""

%%[IF @Date == "Monday" THEN]%%
    [@Subject=Objet A]
%%[ELSEIF IF @Date == "Tuesday" THEN]%%
    [@Subject=Objet B]

%%[ELSEIF IF @Date == "Wednesday" THEN]%%
    [@Subject=Objet c]

%%[ELSEIF IF @Date == "Thursday" THEN]%%
    [@Subject=Objet E]

%%[ELSEIF IF @Date == "Friday" THEN]%%
    [@Subject=Objet D]
%%[ELSEIF IF @Date == "Saturday" THEN]%%
    [@Subject=Objet F]
%%[ELSEIF IF @Date == "Sunday" THEN]%%
    [@Subject=Objet G]
%%[ELSE]%%
    [Objet base]
%%[ENDIF]%%

]%%

%%=v(@Subject)=%%
```

I'm a noob in ampscript so my syntax is probably false :)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can try this piece of code:

```
%%[ VAR @Date, @Subject 
SET @Date = FORMAT(Now(), "ddddd") 
IF @Date == "Monday" THEN 
SET @Subject = "Monday subject line" 
ELSEIF @Date == "Tuesday" THEN 
SET @Subject = "Tuesday subject line" 
ELSEIF @Date == "Wednesday" THEN 
SET @Subject = "Wednesday subject line" 
ELSEIF @Date == "Thursday" THEN 
SET @Subject = "Thursday subject line" 
ELSEIF @Date == "Friday" THEN 
SET @Subject = "Friday subject line" 
ELSEIF @Date == "Saturday" THEN 
SET @Subject = "Saturday subject line" 
ELSEIF @Date == "Sunday" THEN 
SET @Subject = "Sunday subject line" 
ELSE 
SET @Subject = "Default subject line" ENDIF ]%%
```

In your subject line, you can paste %%=v(@Subject)=%% This will populate the subject line as per the day of the week. I am not sure why you have DateAdd function in your code. If you need to adjust the dates, you can use it as per your requirement.

Comment: Thanks it 's working  ! Have a good week end :)